# CSS3 TOGGLE HTML5

Tags: html, css, toggle

I made an animation with CSS3, i've already do that in other page but this now don't work and i don't know why please help me! I don't see my mistake i have already test position : absolute but nothing.

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<header id="header">
    <nav>
                <div id="toggle">
                    <div class="one"></div>
                    <div class="two"></div>
                    <div class="three"></div>
                </div>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

and this my CSS3 :

```
#toggle {
  width: 28px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  opacity: 0.5;

}

#toggle:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
}


#toggle div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  margin: 4px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;

}

#toggle.on .one {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

#toggle.on .two {
  opacity: 0;
}

#toggle.on .three {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}

#header{
 position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);   
}
```

Thanx a lot for your answers !

Comment: what's adding the class `on`? And what is the problem? "doesn't work" doesn't describe anything.

Comment: don't make the animation but is good the answer of user20303

Comment: it don't do the animation please ... i want to do this animation when i clic on the middle the second bar and after the same when i clic another time

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to rotate when you click on them, use this:

```
#toggle .one:active {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}

#toggle .two:active {
opacity: 0;
}

#toggle .three:active {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(7px, -8px);
}
```

Comment: "toggle.on is not specified in the HTML." That's why we ask what causes it before supposing a solution. You could be right.

Comment: I think he meant to do :hover.

Comment: Thanx a lot it's work but what is the other word for make the same like ON?? and which work

Comment: i don't want to do an hover i want to do a click please

Comment: sorry , but i want to do this on clic not on hover

Comment: Read the answer again.

Comment: yes but i want to do that for one click on the toggle and  after an other click they stop animation

Comment: Alex I don't mean to be rude but you should have at least a minimal understanding of what you're doing. Your question doesn't describe a specific problem, user20303 gave a reasonable answer assuming that he/she correctly guessed the problem. It would be useful to clarify, in the question, what "don't work", what should happen and when.